# How to serialize a List<T> into XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How to convert this list:

```
List<int> Branches = new List<int>();
Branches.Add(1);
Branches.Add(2);
Branches.Add(3);
```

into this XML:

```
<Branches>
    <branch id="1" />
    <branch id="2" />
    <branch id="3" />
</Branches>
```

Comment: Start here then come back with a specific question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.aspx

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can try this using LINQ:

```
List<int> Branches = new List<int>();
Branches.Add(1);
Branches.Add(2);
Branches.Add(3);

XElement xmlElements = new XElement("Branches", Branches.Select(i => new XElement("branch", i)));
System.Console.Write(xmlElements);
System.Console.Read();
```

Output:

```
<Branches>
  <branch>1</branch>
  <branch>2</branch>
  <branch>3</branch>
</Branches>
```

Forgot to mention: you need to include `using System.Xml.Linq;` namespace.

**EDIT:**

`XElement xmlElements = new XElement("Branches", Branches.Select(i => new XElement("branch", new XAttribute("id", i))));`

output:

```
<Branches>
  <branch id="1" />
  <branch id="2" />
  <branch id="3" />
</Branches>
```

Comment: This won't output `<branch id="1" />` it will output `<branch>1</branch>`.

Comment: Did you mean `new XElement("branch", new XAttribute("id", i))`

Comment: @James,@lisp Thanks for correcting me.  I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Linq-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

```
List<int> Branches = new List<int>();
Branches.Add(1);
Branches.Add(2);
Branches.Add(3);

var branchesXml = Branches.Select(i => new XElement("branch",
                                                    new XAttribute("id", i)));
var bodyXml = new XElement("Branches", branchesXml);
System.Console.Write(bodyXml);
```

Or create the appropriate class structure and use [XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx).

```
[XmlType(Name = "branch")]
public class Branch
{
    [XmlAttribute(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

var branches = new List<Branch>();
branches.Add(new Branch { Id = 1 });
branches.Add(new Branch { Id = 2 });
branches.Add(new Branch { Id = 3 });

// Define the root element to avoid ArrayOfBranch
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Branch>),
                                   new XmlRootAttribute("Branches"));
using(var stream = new StringWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(stream, branches);
    System.Console.Write(stream.ToString());
}
```