# convert list to xml in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, list

I have a list of string. I need to convert it into an xml document. Am using XElement to achieve this.

```
   List<string> list= myString.Split(',').ToList();

  XElement xmlElements = new XElement("Root", new XElement("Number",list.Select(i => new XElement("Num", i)))); 
               System.Console.Write(xmlElements);
               System.Console.Read();
```

I get the below format.

```
<Root>
 <Number>
  <Num></Num>
 <Num></Num>
 </Number>
</Root>
```

But I need something like this.

```
 <Root>
  <Number id=1>
    <Num></Num>
  </Number>
 <Number id=2>
   <Num></Num>
 </Number>
</Root>
```

How to achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert list to XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043663/convert-list-to-xml)

Answer (score 7):

If by an `id` you mean an index, then:

```
XElement xmlElements = 
    new XElement("Root",        
        list.Select((i, index) => new XElement("Number", 
                                      new XAttribute("id", index),
                                      new XElement("Num", i))));
```

The result for the "a,b,c" will be

```
<Root>
  <Number id="0">
    <Num>a</Num>
  </Number>
  <Number id="1">
    <Num>b</Num>
  </Number>
  <Number id="2">
    <Num>c</Num>
  </Number>
</Root>
```