# converting a list data to xml format using c# mvc

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I get my data retrieved in this way

```
var parentData = dataContext.Fetch<MakerCheckerViewModel>  
(PetaPoco.Sql.Builder.Append  
  ("SELECT MakerCheckerId  
  ,ModelName  
  ,mkCk.CheckerStatusId  
  ,chkSt.CheckerStatusName  
  FROM MakerChecker as mkCk  
  JOIN CheckerStatus as chkSt ON  
mkCk.CheckerStatusId=chkSt.CheckerStatusId")  
).ToList();
```

I need to convert it into json. I referred these links [How to convert JSON to XML or XML to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814001/convert-json-string-to-xml-or-xml-to-json-string) but using this it can convert only the string data but not the list types.
Also I cannot do it inside Linq as done here [convert list to xml in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672080/convert-list-to-xml-in-c-sharp) as I have the bunch data which will be increasing more in future so I need something like this

```
    var parentDataJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parentData);
```

which is done to convert to json. So similar functionality would be there for xml data too. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

This will return a string of XML.

```
public string CreateXml(MyObject myObject)
{
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(myObject.GetType());

    using (var xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, myObject);
        xmlStream.Position = 0;
        xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
        return xmlDoc.InnerXml;
    }
}
```