# How do I create and fill an xml file?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to create and fill an xml file with information. I'm unsure of what to do to make it work. I have a list of items. The list is of type `IEnumerable`. The Items are of my class `MyItem`. `MyItem` has those types in it:

```
public class MyItem
   {
      public Guid MyID { get; set; }
      public String MyString { get; set; }
   }
```

I was able to create an xml file.

```
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(myPath);

        System.Xml.XmlDocument file = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(di.FullName + "\\test.xml", FileMode.Create))
        {
            file.Save(fs);
        }
```

But how could I fill `test.xml` with the list of items?

I was imagining to fill my xml file like this:

```
<MyFiles>
   <MyFile>
      <MyID> *Guid here* </MyID>
      <MyString> *String here* </MyString> 
   </MyFile>

   <MyFile>
      <MyID> *Guid2 here* </MyID>
      <MyString> *String2 here* </MyString> 
   </MyFile>
</MyFiles>
```

Comment: You can use LINQ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043663/how-to-serialize-a-listt-into-xml

Answer (score 0):

You could use the XmlDocument class, and then append elements as you need to, see example:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument( );

    //(1) the xml declaration is recommended, but not mandatory
    XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration( "1.0", "UTF-8", null );
    XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
    doc.InsertBefore( xmlDeclaration, root );

    //(2) string.Empty makes cleaner code
    XmlElement element1 = doc.CreateElement( string.Empty, "body", string.Empty );
    doc.AppendChild( element1 );

    XmlElement element2 = doc.CreateElement( string.Empty, "level1", string.Empty );
    element1.AppendChild( element2 );

    XmlElement element3 = doc.CreateElement( string.Empty, "level2", string.Empty );
    XmlText text1 = doc.CreateTextNode( "text" );
    element3.AppendChild( text1 );
    element2.AppendChild( element3 );

    XmlElement element4 = doc.CreateElement( string.Empty, "level2", string.Empty );
    XmlText text2 = doc.CreateTextNode( "other text" );
    element4.AppendChild( text2 );
    element2.AppendChild( element4 );

    doc.Save( "D:\\document.xml" );
```

Comment: Hi. I've tried what you recommended and I just need 1 problem solved. I have a list of items. I use foreach() for this. But whenever doc.save() is called only 1 item is saved. Is there a way to add something into the xml?

Answer (score 0):

Use XMLSerializer for serializing the objects to xml

```
using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FileName))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyItem));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, MyItem);
        writer.Flush();
    }
```